# Passar string de conexão para o dataset via código

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net

Como passar a *string* de conexão para o *dataset* via código? pois a aplicação que estou desenvolvendo não pode conter o `app.config`.

Comment: E o que você quer saber? Tem algum código para demonstrar o que deseja?

Comment: Ao criar um dataset, o visual studio já inclui automaticamente um arquivo app.config com a conexão ao banco de dados. Gostaria de passar a string de conexão via código, para que não necessite deste arquivo.

Comment: Ok, mas quer fazer como, em que código. Pode por qualquer coisa que você se vira?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tem segredo:

```
var connectionString = "Data Source=MSSQL;Initial Catalog=SeuBanco; Integrated Security=true;";
using (var connection = new SqlConnection()) {
    connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    connection.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("Estado: {0}", connection.State);
    Console.WriteLine("ConnectionString: {0}", connection.ConnectionString);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DataBase/ConnectionStringDataset.cs).

Outras possibilidades de *strings* (o ideal é não ter senhas soltas assim):

```
Server=localhost;Database=meuDB;User Id=meuUsername;Password=minhaPassword;

Server=10.0.0.1,1433;Database=meuDB;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Tenha cuidado para não colocar a string de conexão no código.** Avalie onde seu componente vai ser usado (tipo e aplicação e ache um método correto para armazenar a string de configuração.

Se seu componente vai ser usado em uma aplicação web, você pode usar o web.config, se é desktop o app.config, se não quiser nenhum dos dois, use um txt externo ao aplicativo porque manutenções sao geralmente triviais de fazer e alterar uma string de conexão não deve exigir recompilar o codigo.

Você pode isolar essa lógica de configuração em uma Factory ou deixar a camada superior (caso use arquitetura em camadas) instanciar corretamente o repositorio. Passando essas configurações ao construtor.